# What is the role of Surface{ properties:{} }?

Tags: famo.us

Where does {pointerEvents: 'none'} belong on a Surface?

From the Famo.us University "Timbre" example:
http://famo.us/university/famous-102/timbre/24/

```
function _createIcon() {
    var iconSurface = new ImageSurface({
        size: [this.options.iconSize, this.options.iconSize],
        content : this.options.iconUrl,
        pointerEvents : 'none'
    });
```

And from:
http://famo.us/university/famous-102/timbre/25/

```
function _createTitle() {
    var titleSurface = new Surface({
        size: [true, true],
        content: this.options.title,
        properties: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: this.options.fontSize + 'px',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            pointerEvents : 'none'
        }
    });
```

According to the Surface documentation:
http://famo.us/docs/0.2.0/core/Surface
**properties**: is a

> string dictionary of **HTML** attributes to set on target div

The "PointerEvent Interface" is defined by the W3C
http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#pointerevent-interface
so it seems appropriate to include it in the properties object.

But, if pointerEvents can be used both inside and outside the properties object, does the properties object have any real meaning? Is the Surface object ultimately just flattened out?

Or do Surface and ImageSurface handle properties differently? I can't tell from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations! You found a bug in famo.us University!

I visited your link and inspected the icon that was meant to have it's pointer events value set. Rather than "none" the value was "auto" (from the base famous-surface CSS class used in famo.us university)

In page 25 of the tutorial `pointer-events` is in the correct position (within the properties object)

options that are not valid html attributes are simply discounted by the browser. Everything in the properties object is applied to the style attribute of the Surface's

The only difference between an `ImageSurface` and a normal `Surface` is that `ImageSurface` is a `<img>` and not a `<div>`

It also has a premade `src` property to store the url of an image, where with a `Surface` you would need to write something on the lines of  in the `content` property.

Comment: Kraig, I've submitted other corrections to suggestions@famo.us. Maybe there should be a FU bug report link on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Shu from famo.us here.

Thanks for pointing this out. Kraig, you're right on the money. This has been fixed.